# Update information in database asynchronously

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to update the information in the database asynchronously, what is the difference between the following implementation, both are asynchronous?

Which one is better to use?

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
 userModel.Update(); //update the database
}).Start();

internal async void ProcessMessageReceived(UserModel userModel) {
 userModel.Update();
}
```

Comment: second one isn't asynchronous, thread does real work and async is work to be done normally I/O operation

Comment: what is the scope of the first thread, when it will be destroyed, or when it will be finish?

Comment: if its background, its run till main thread runs, whereas for foreground it runs till it needs to run or till completion.

Comment: How can we determine the background or foreground?

Comment: please check this: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: If you mark method as `async`, do some `await` inside, in other case it;s not asynchonous. Also,. `async void` should be used only for event handlers and not for other methods

Answer (score 1):

Your first implementation is using a new thread, while the second seems to be using the [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx). We need to see the implementation of the Update method to be completely sure, I guess its returning a Task?

Using the TPL is normally more efficient than spawning your own threads.

TPL tasks use the thread pool and allow the re usability of Tasks which can provide extra performance advantages.